# How do i search for email.ne => ['', nil] in mongoid?

Tags: mongoid

I would like to do the following in Mongoid:

```
user_infos = User.where( :"email".ne => ["",nil])
```

Where the user's email is no blank and is not nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
User.where(:email.nin => ["", nil]).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
User.where(:email.ne => "", :email.exists => true).to_a
```